# bs_embed_popover HTML tags in content variable

Tags: html, r, shiny, popover

I'm trying to put a link to a url into `content` var of `bs_embed_popover` function for a R shiny app
[Documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/bsplus/versions/0.1.1/topics/bs_embed_popover) says

> content: character, content for the popover body, can be HTML

However, I see the tag appearing as plain character in the shiny app
Anything I'm missing? 
[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(bsplus)
library(htmltools)
library(shinydashboard)

# UI
ui <-   
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Titles"),
    dashboardSidebar(
      use_bs_popover(),
      selectInput(
        inputId = "letter",
        label = "Label with popover help",
        choices = c("a", "b", "c")
      ) %>%
        shinyInput_label_embed(
          shiny_iconlink() %>%
            bs_embed_popover(
              title = "Letter", content = paste0("Choose a favorite","<a href='www.google.com'>  Test link </a>")
              , placement ="right"
            )
        )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      tags$style(HTML('.popover-title {color:black;}
                      .popover-content {color:black;}
                      .main-sidebar {z-index:1;}')
    )

  ))

# Server
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {    
})

# Run the applicationenter image description here
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Have you tried `content = HTML(paste0(......` ?

Comment: yes @StéphaneLaurent but no luck. Still doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

You can add the instruction `html="true"` after the `content=HTML(paste0(....` instruction, like this:

```
bs_embed_popover(
              title="Letter"
              , content=paste0("Choose a favorite","<a href='www.google.com'>  Test link </a>")
              , placement="right"
              , html="true"
            )
```